# How to load only few columns into a dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading a file into a `df`.

```
df=spark.read.csv("path")
```

If I try above way,
It will load the whole `CSV` file, which has 20 columns, but I want to read just 5 out of it. Is there a way??

Comment: val sourceDf = spark.read.csv(...)
val df1 = sourceDF.select("first column", "second column", "third column")

Comment: But I want it to happen while reading the file itself..

Comment: it won't matter because spark uses DAG to load only data that is used for collect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform your selection before reading.

```
df=spark.read.csv("path")
        .select(my_cols)
```

For better reading (and writing) performances, You should convert your CSV to Parquet file which is a columnar storage format.

Comment: But this is same as 
df=spark.read.csv("path")
df=df.select(my_cols)

Right??

Comment: Can we select required columns while reading the file itself??